# Multivarient LSTM data Preprocessing

Tags: python, lstm

[image]The code shown work perfectly for validation data, not for training,Help me to find the mistake.

`

```
 window = 23
 forecast = 23
 TRAIN_SPLIT = 2000
 x_train, y_train = multi_data_prep(X_data, Y_data, 0,     
 TRAIN_SPLIT, window, forecast)
 x_vali, y_vali = multi_data_prep(X_data, Y_data, TRAIN_SPLIT, 
 None, window, forecast)
 x_train.shape, y_train.shape, x_vali.shape, y_vali.shape 

  def multi_data_prep(X_data, Y_data, start, end, window, 
  horizon):
  X = []
  y = []
  start = start + window
  if end is None:
  end = len(X_data) - horizon
  for i in range(start, end):
  indices = range(i-window, i)
  X.append(X_data[indices])
  indicey = range(i+1, i+1+horizon)
  y.append(Y_data[indicey])
  return np.array(X), np.array(y)
```

`
received the out put as
((0,), (0,), (444, 23, 4), (444, 23, 1))

Comment: Hey, please fix your code indentation and provide (preferably shortened) examples for `X_data` and `Y_data` such that your example is working and will reproduce the problem.

Comment: Not get your points Wallraff. Do you mean indentation problem.

Comment: The formatting of your code is wrong, there is for example one space too much in the beginning of the `def` line, and the lines afterwards should be shifted to the right by (conventionally) four spaces. If you fix that and provide examples for `X_data` and `Y_data`, people might be able to help you.

Comment: Now you may get the actual arrangement of code, while copy & past in post ...the alignment was changed.But actual  shown in picture view.

Comment: You could just have edited the code; that would have been more useful than a screenshot if someone wanted to run your code.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you did not implement something useful for the case that `end` is not `None`; you just return numpy arrays of the empty lists `X` and `y`.

Edit: That's also the reason why I asked in the comments about the indentation: it really matters in Python. You probably want to unindent the `for` loop such that it gets executed in both cases.